# Resizing a form introduces visual artifacts on bottom docked controls

Tags: winforms, resize, docking

I am working on a "bottom-right docked" popup form.
The layout of the form follows this structure:

- Header
- Content (text message)
- Footer

This form should resize according to its content.
I am using SetBounds to make it grow to the top instead of the bottom (remember that the window is docked bottom-right).

However, when the animation occurs, the footer redraws itself in a very bad way, as its form-relative location is continuously updated.

I provide a sample to give you an idea:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AnimatorTest
{
    public class Form3 : Form
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        public Form3()
        {
            timer.Interval = 30;
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;

            // Create 3 test buttons
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Button b = new Button() { Dock = DockStyle.Bottom };
                b.Click += (s, e) => timer.Start();
                b.Text = "Click and watch how ugly I am during the animation.";
                Controls.Add(b);
            }

            Height = 100;
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            int desiredHeight = 500;
            int difference = desiredHeight - Height;
            int change = difference / 6;
            if (System.Math.Abs(change) < 1)
            {
                SetBounds(Left, Top - difference, Width, Height + difference);
                timer.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                SetBounds(Left, Top - change, Width, Height + change);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really have any idea to work around this.
Thanks.

Comment: why not using anchor?

Comment: hello, either dock or anchor produces the exact same visual artifacts.